# DAO with different DataSource for different cases

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I access a REST API to get some objects in order to save them in a local DB. Later I want to access these objects in the local DB and update them as well.

I'm not sure what is the best way to go - trying to use the DAO Design Pattern. What I see is, that there are different data sources for different cases (operations).

Can you give me some ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First advice: do NOT overcomplicate your solution if it's not  necessary.

If you are using the same DB instance for read and write operations, just create  single pair of the DAO interface\implementation for all operations

Additionally, API call should NEVER reach data access layer directly. Add business service layer in between.

API -> Business Service(s) -> DAO -> DB